# Out of screen window

Tags: screen, window

Windows that I drag half way out of the screen return when I click on another application.  How do I keep them off of the screen (desktop)? Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

You can move a window to another workspace, so, you won't see that window until you switch the workspace that you moved window to. To do so, right click on the title of the window and select one of the "Move to Workspace *" options.

For example, if you move a window to workspace right, you can switch to that workspace with 'ctrl + alt + right arrow'.